# How do I iterate over a 'count' resource in Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, loops, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

In this example, I'm trying to create 3 EC2 instances which each have an elastic IP assigned. I want to achieve this by saying the following.

```
resource "aws_instance" "web_servers" {
  ami                         = "ami-09e67e426f25ce0d7"
  instance_type               = "t3.micro"
  ...
  count = 3
}
```

and, along with other networking instances,

```
resource "aws_eip" "elastic_ip" {
  for_each = aws_instance.web_servers
  instance = each.key
  vpc      = true
}
```

However, this is saying the following:

```
The given "for_each" argument value is unsuitable: the "for_each" argument must be a map, or set of strings, and you have provided a value of type tuple.
```

I have tried wrapping the `for_each` in a `toset()` which also says there is an issue with an unknown number of instances - I know there are 3 though. Is there something I'm missing around the `count` & `for_each` keywords?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you really want to use `for_each`, rather then count again, it should be:

```
resource "aws_eip" "elastic_ip" {
  for_each = {for idx, val in aws_instance.web_servers: idx => val}
  instance = each.value.id
  vpc      = true
}
```

But since you are using `count` in the first place, it would be probably better to use `count` for your `aws_eip` as well:

```
resource "aws_eip" "elastic_ip" {
  count    = length(aws_instance.web_servers)
  instance = aws_instance.web_servers[count.index].id
  vpc      = true
}
```

Comment: What would you do if you needed to iterate over 2 sets of resources? this would work for only 1-1 mappings.

Answer (score 0):

In AWS is your instance field = EC2 ID = ARN?

If so you may be able to access the `arn` attribute in the `aws_instance` resource block.

You could try `toset(aws_instance.web_servers.arn)` and keep `instance = each.key`. I generally just use `each.value` but they should be the same when dealing with a set.